# Swift Concurrency - non-blocking sleep()?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await

Swift has access to Darwin's `sleep` call which is simple to use:

```swift
sleep(10) // waits for 10 seconds, but blocks the thread
```

However, this blocks the current thread.
Now that Swift has support for `async`/`await` is there a built-in, non-blocking `sleep` method that does not suspend the current thread?

```swift
// what I'm looking for:

func doWork() async {
    // ...
    await sleep(10) // lightweight, does not block thread
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but FYI: you don't want to suspend the current thread. You want the the current Task context to wait, which is different. Async/await is an abstraction over co-routines (not threads), which readily get moved between threads, and are designed expressly with the purpose of never blocking threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it. There's a built-in method on `Task` (part of the Swift standard library) that offers this sleeping functionality to *suspend* the current task without blocking the thread.
The Swift runtime achieves this by adding a "suspension point" during runtime so the thread will be free to execute other code and will only return to the function when the task resumes.

"Tasks" are a construct offered by Swift's "structured concurrency" to aid with dispatching multiple workloads concurrently.
Anyone else interested can [read more about it here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0304-structured-concurrency.md).

```swift
func doWork() async {
    // ...
    await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1)) // lightweight, does not block thread
    // ... 
}
```